Get the Unicode block or script name for a particular character (code point) in Java
I see the Character class has two nested enums:

Character.UnicodeBlock
Character.UnicodeScript

For a particular character, how do I get the appropriate block or script enum object? I expected a pair of methods such as  Character.getUnicodeBlock( codePoint ) & Character.getUnicodeScript( codePoint ). But I do not see such methods.

Use enum method of
Look on each enum class rather than Character class. You will find each enum offers an of method to which you can pass a code point.

Character.UnicodeBlock.of( codePoint )
Character.UnicodeScript.of( codePoint )

Example:
int codePoint = 2_309;
String text = Character.toString( codePoint );
Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of( codePoint );
Character.UnicodeScript script = Character.UnicodeScript.of( codePoint );

System.out.println( "text = " + text );
System.out.println( "block = " + block );
System.out.println( "script = " + script );


text = अ
block = DEVANAGARI
script = DEVANAGARI

Example usage
We can use the of method to find all the characters of a particular script.
IntStream
        .rangeClosed( Character.MIN_CODE_POINT , Character.MAX_CODE_POINT )
        .filter( ( int codePoint ) -> Character.UnicodeScript.of( codePoint ) == Character.UnicodeScript.DEVANAGARI )
        .mapToObj( ( int codePoint ) -> codePoint + ":" + Character.toString( codePoint ) )
        .forEach( System.out :: println );

When run:
2304:ऀ
2305:ँ
2306:ं
2307:ः
2308:ऄ
2309:अ
2310:आ
…

